# Cannot deserialize a 'List<T>' from BsonType 'Document'

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm using MongoDB Driver 2.3.0 in my C# MVC application and getting this error:

> "Cannot deserialize a 'List' from BsonType 'Document'"

While fetching data after update.
Below is my code:

```
IMongoCollection<Model> objModel = dbHelper.GetCollection<Model>(Model.CollectionName);

var query = Builders<Model>.Filter.And(
    Builders<Model>.Filter.Eq("_id", new ObjectId(Id)),
    Builders<Model>.Filter.Eq("locations.locationid", objLocation.locationid));
var update = Builders<Model>.Update.Set("locations", objLocation.ToBsonDocument());
var result = objModel.UpdateMany(query, update, new UpdateOptions { IsUpsert = true });

if (objLocation.isdefaultlocation)
{
    var lList = (from e in objModel.AsQueryable<Model>()
                 where e._id == ObjectId.Parse(Id)
                 select e.locations).FirstOrDefault();

    lList.Where(i => i.isdefaultlocation == true && i.locationid != objLocation.locationid).ToList()
         .ForEach(s => s.isdefaultlocation = false);

    Model onjO = new Model();
    onjO.locations = lList;
    var query1 = Builders<Model>.Filter.Eq("_id", new ObjectId(Id));
    var update1 = Builders<Model>.Update.Set("locations", MongoDB.Bson.BsonArray.Create(onjO.ToBsonDocument()["locations"]));
    objModel.UpdateMany(query1, update1);
}

return (result.ModifiedCount > 0);
```

And I am able to update record but when I try to fetch record using Linq query I get above mentioned Error. Below is the code where I get error:

```
var lList = (from e in objModel.AsQueryable<Model>()
                     where e._id == ObjectId.Parse(Id)
                     select e.locations).FirstOrDefault();
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK, You don't need `objLocation.ToBsonDocument()`, using `objLocation` should work !?